# Jetty Hook for TCP/IP connection early revocation (avoiding accept())

Tags: security, jetty, hook, tcp, connector

I am looking for a Hook allowing me to tell/instruct the ServerConnector (or whatever other object in the Jetty architecture that would be a more suitable hook-point) NOT to accept an incoming TCP/IP connection on the Web Server ports (eg: 80 or 443) based on the IP address of the remote party (because that is all the info there is available before accept() is called and before, LATER after accept, the HTTP data becomes available from the TCP/IP frame's payload).

The idea is that I would attach a peace of software to that hook that for each incoming connection can say : Accept/Revoke.
With revoke the incoming connection would be IGNORED and the socket would stay closed avoiding the Jetty container to do more work/use resources on it.

It would also make it possible to protect system features (eg. special admin menu) after certain server ports by only accepting, for example, local addresses (10.32....), etc. It would have been even nicer to ALSO be able to get to the MAC address of the connecting  device and only allow access if the MAC address is in an authorisation list (=the user had physical access to the LAN to connect his device or else his MAC address would never be the one that is seen on the LAN because there is no peer to peer MAC address exchange if not on the same LAN).

In this way I intend to prevent hostile connections to consume CPU, bandwidth and sockets just to send them the 'main' pages during attacks and force them into waiting for time-outs. At the same time it would additionally allow to protect access to non public features based on 'physical local access'. The hook software could even revoke connections on parts of the IP address, for instance the Chinese IP address range, etc.

I found the typical TCP/IP socket interface on the ServerConnector classes (open/close/accept/...) but I didn't find a place where I could register for a pre-accept() hook or callback. I also looked at the ServerConnector's class ancestors but I didn't really see anything of the sorts either. I started with [org.eclipse.jetty.server Class ServerConnector](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html#accept-int-)

For clarity, and for people that are more confortabel with code, this would conceptually represent in code what I look for.

```
...setup Jetty server, Factories, etc

ServerConnector http2=new ServerConnector(this.oServer,sslF,alpnF,h2F,https2F);
http2.setPort(8443);

http2.setPreAcceptHook(8843, oMyHook); <---INVENTED line

this.oServer.addConnector(http2);
```

The hook would be a simple method of the MyHook object that returns true or false.

```
boolean AcceptRevoke(IP, Port) <--return true=accept, false=revoke
```

I would welcome any hint as to what direction to look in (a class name or so) or a confirmation that such feature is not available or cannot be and therefore never will be available. There may be constraints in container design that would not allow a pre-accept revocation, like those one can do with socket libraries, that I am not aware of and hence would be looking for an impossibility.

Many Thanks.

Product and Versions Info: 
Jetty 9.3.0 (v20150612)
alpn-boot-8.1.3 (v20150130)
JRE 8 (Oracle 1.8.0 Build 45 - b15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **A LOT OF WORK** ahead of you.

To do this, you'll essentially have to provide your own `Socket` implementation layer for Java.  There is no layer you can hook onto in Jetty that allows you to do anything that you mentioned.  The kinds of things you want to do are at a much lower level, something at the JVM and/or OS levels.

You'll need to handle [`java.net.Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), [`java.net.ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html), and [`java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html).

Which means you'll be writing your own [`javax.net.ServerSocketFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ServerSocketFactory.html), [`javax.net.SocketFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html), [`java.net.SocketImpl`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/SocketImpl.html), and [`java.net.SocketImplFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/SocketImplFactory.html) for regular Sockets.

And for SSL/TLS, you'll need to write/handle/manage your own [`javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html), [`javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket.html), [`javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html), and [`javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocketFactory.html).

And don't forget to grab all of the [jetty-alpn](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-alpn) code additions to the standard OpenJDK SSL libraries so that you can get HTTP/2 working for you as well (seeing as you are obviously using it, based on your question details)

Before you test this on Jetty, test your implementation on a simple ServerSocket and ServerSocketChannel setup.

After you confirm it does what you want, then you'll need to wire it up into Jetty.  For normal ServerSocket / ServerSocketChannel, you'll have to work with the system-wide the [`java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/SelectorProvider.html)

For SSLServerSocket / SSLServerSocketChannel, you'll wire it up via a custom/overridden [`org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.html) implementation of your own.

**Or ...**

You can use a combination of post-accept logic (built into Jetty) and OS level management of connections (such as iptables), which would be far simpler.

The requirement you stated to hook into a point before accept is possible with a Java server, but is a special kind of effort where you extend the core Java networking and Socket behaviors.

Comment: Joakim, thanks but this is not a solution within my reach. I want to stay in standard Jetty for obvious reasons. There is no way I am going to be able to maintain my own version of the above classes over time let alone produce them in the quality the Jetty team can do it. I would/could loose all the advantages of using Jetty because I could jeopardize its robustness, speed , etc. In case of problems I would always have to wonder if I am not cluttering stackoverflow with problems that I have created myself in those classes.

Comment: Nothing about what I recommended will break Jetty or cause it to use non-standard Jetty.  In fact the Jetty code is barely touched.  All of the work would be at a level before Jetty even gets involved.

Comment: Ok, I see, indeed the classes you list are at the under-side so to speak at the java level. What you suggest has the advantage that the socket would indeed stay closed and the accept queue (at set depth) would not be encumbered with the filtered connection attempts. I'll look into that because as greg said in his solution the User Agent will still see an open+immediate close. So your suggestion is more work but fits the intended functionality. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could probably just override the configure(Socket socket) method of the ServerConnector. If you want to reject the socket, just close the connection. This might cause some strange exceptions, if so report them in Bugzilla and we'll clean up.

Alternatively, open a Bugzilla to ask us to make the accepted(Socket socket) method protected instead of private and you can reject there.

Note that with either of these, the client will see the connection as accepted and then immediately close.

Comment: greg, thanks. I have been thinking along those lines in another alternative, that is, make a class that inherits ServerConnector and only overwrites the accept(ID) method. Revoking would simply mean not calling the parent class accpet(). I figured that without accept() being called the socket would stay closed. However I fear the consequences because the accept() method returns void and the code calling it may not become aware that the socket was not accepted (by suppression behind its back), resulting in leaks, pending allocation and possible throws. Would this however be a solution?

Comment: you are missing what @gregw is saying, java and jetty will still accept, and from the point of view of the tcp/ip connection at the OS and java levels are accepted.  It is at that point you apply your logic and forcibly close the connection or let Jetty process it.  This is the approach being suggested by greg.